# Docker two tier application issue: failed to connect to mongo container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a simple nodeJS application consisting of the frontend and a mongo database. I want to deploy it via Docker.

In my docker-compose file I have the following:

```
version: '2'
services:
  express-container:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
     - mongo-container
  mongo-container:
    image: mongo:3.0
```

When I run docker-compose up, I have the following error:

```
Creating todoangularv2_mongo-container_1 ...
Creating todoangularv2_mongo-container_1 ... done
Creating todoangularv2_express-container_1 ...
Creating todoangularv2_express-container_1 ... done
Attaching to todoangularv2_mongo-container_1, todoangularv2_express-container_1
mongo-container_1    | 2017-07-25T15:26:09.863+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=25f03f51322b
mongo-container_1    | 2017-07-25T15:26:09.864+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.15
mongo-container_1    | 2017-07-25T15:26:09.864+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: b8ff507269c382bc100fc52f75f48d54cd42ec3b
mongo-container_1    | 2017-07-25T15:26:09.864+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-166-66-3 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
mongo-container_1    | 2017-07-25T15:26:09.864+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
mongo-container_1    | 2017-07-25T15:26:09.864+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
mongo-container_1    | 2017-07-25T15:26:09.923+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
mongo-container_1    | 2017-07-25T15:26:09.924+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
express-container_1  | Listening on port 3000
express-container_1  |
express-container_1  | events.js:72
express-container_1  |         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
express-container_1  |               ^
express-container_1  | Error: failed to connect to [mongo-container:27017]
```

So my frontend cannot reach the mongo container called 'mongo-container' in the docker-compose file. In the application itself I'm giving the URL for the mongo database as follows:

```
module.exports = {
    url : 'mongodb://mongo-container:27017/todo'
}
```

Any idea how I can change my application so that when it is run on Docker, I don't have this connectivity issue?

EDIT: the mongo container gives the following output:

```
WAUTERW-M-T3ZT:vagrant wim$ docker logs f63
2017-07-26T09:15:02.824+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=f637f963c87f
2017-07-26T09:15:02.825+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.15
2017-07-26T09:15:02.825+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: b8ff507269c382bc100fc52f75f48d54cd42ec3b
...
2017-07-26T09:15:21.461+0000 I STORAGE  [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /data/db/local.0, size: 64MB,  took 0.024 secs
2017-07-26T09:15:21.476+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

The express container gives the following output:

```
WAUTERW-M-T3ZT:vagrant wim$ docker logs 25a
Listening on port 3000

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: failed to connect to [mongo-container:27017]
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:555:74)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:156:15)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:534:10)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:441:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

EDIT: the issue appeared in the Dockerfile. Here is a corrected one (simplified a bit as I started from a node image rather than an Ubuntu image):

```
FROM node:0.10.40
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
CMD ["node", "/usr/src/app/bin/www"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could substitute `depends_on` by `links` session, that express dependency between services like `depends_on` and, according to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#links), containers for the linked service will be reachable at a hostname identical to the alias, or the service name if no alias was specified.

```
version: '2'
services:
  express-container:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "3000:3000"
    links:
     - "mongo-container"
  mongo-container:
    image: mongo:3.0
```

Comment: Do not use links, this will be depracated(https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/). After Docker 1.9, service discovery works fine by just using container name. Your compose file looks fine and you should be able to connect between services using name. can u check "docker-compose ps", "docker ps" and "docker logs mongo" to make sure it got started fine. i think the container did not start or its not yet up. depends_on (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on) does not make sure that service is fully up, you need to manage it in the app.

Comment: I used links, but does not work. In fact, I get the same error. I edited the original post with the output of docker logs. The mongo container is up and running for sure, however the express container goes into fail as it cannot find 'mongo-container'. I'm running using docker-compose, not on Docker Swarm or Kubernetes, so not sure if service discovery is there? I'm using docker version 17.06.0-ce

Comment: I think your mongodb container is not yet fully up when your express container is started. To prove this timing issue, can you try restarting the express container that failed and see if it works. If that does not work, pls send the "docker inspect <cid>" for both containers. (service discovery works without swarm. )

Comment: Thanks. I solved it in the meantime. It appeared to be an issue in the Dockerfile. I have corrected it and edited the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appeared in the Dockerfile. Here is a corrected one (simplified a bit as I started from a node image rather than an Ubuntu image):

```
FROM node:0.10.40
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
CMD ["node", "/usr/src/app/bin/www"]
```